# NoClassDefFoundError using ivy. Jars not adding to classpath

Tags: maven, ivy, ivyde

It seems that the jars I pulled from my maven repo are not getting put into my java classpath. I thought the ivy cache took care of this?

Whenever I run a class either in eclipse or outside eclipse I get NoClassDefFoundError. 
It compiles fine but doesn't work at runtime. My dependency conf is set to runtime->default so I thought this would work.

Below is the files Im using. Am I doing something wrong?

ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="org_test" module="mod_test" />
    <configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application" />
    <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile" />
    <conf name="test" description="Required for test only" extends="runtime" />
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact ext="jar" />
        <artifact ext="pom" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.apache.solr" name="solr-core" rev="3.5.0" conf="runtime->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.solr" name="solr-solrj" rev="3.6.0" conf="runtime->default" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

ivysettings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chained" />
    <property name="maven.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
    <property name="public.repo.url" value="http://${repo.host}:${repo.port}/nexus/content/groups/public/" override="false" />
    <property name="repo.host" value="localhost" override="false" />
    <property name="repo.port" value="8081" override="false" />
    <property name="repo.path" value="nexus/content/repositories" override="false" />
    <property name="retrieve.resolver" value="chained" override="false" />
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="${public.repo.url}" />
        <chain name="chained" returnFirst="false">
            <resolver ref="public" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

common.xml

```
<project name="common" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <dirname property="ivy-support.build.dir" file="${ant.file.ivy-support}" />
    <property name="ivy-support.lib.dir" location="${ivy-support.build.dir}/ivy" />
    <property name="ivy.settings.filename" value="ivysettings.xml" />

    <property name="ivy.install.version" value="2.1.0-rc2" />
    <condition property="ivy.home" value="${env.IVY_HOME}">
      <isset property="env.IVY_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <property name="ivy.home" value="${user.home}/.ant" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${ivy.home}/lib" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy.jar" />

    <target name="download-ivy" unless="offline">

        <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
        <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
        <get src="http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar" 
             dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init-ivy" depends="download-ivy">
      <!-- try to load ivy here from ivy home, in case the user has not already dropped
              it into ant's lib dir (note that the latter copy will always take precedence).
              We will not fail as long as local lib dir exists (it may be empty) and
              ivy is in at least one of ant's lib dir or the local lib dir. -->
        <path id="ivy.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
                 uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
    </target>


    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${ivy-support.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path" loaderref="ivy.lib.loader" />

    <ivy:settings file="${ivy-support.build.dir}/${ivy.settings.filename}" />

    <property name="should.clean.ivy.cache" value="false" />

    <dirname property="ivy-support.build.dir" file="${ant.file.ivy-support}" />
    <property name="ivy-support.lib.dir" location="${ivy-support.build.dir}/ivy" />
    <property name="ivy.settings.filename" value="ivysettings.xml" />

    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${ivy-support.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path" loaderref="ivy.lib.loader" />

    <ivy:settings file="${ivy-support.build.dir}/${ivy.settings.filename}" />

    <target name="clean-ivy-cache" if="clean.ivy.cache.istrue">
        <ivy:cleancache />
    </target>
</project>
```

build.xml

```
<project name="main" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" default="compile">
    <description>Testing Script</description>
    <import file="common.xml" />

    <!--
    ================
    Build properties
    ================
    -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="src/org"/>
    <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="test.classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/test-classes"/>
    <property name="ivy.reports.dir"  location="${build.dir}/ivy-reports"/>
    <property name="test.reports.dir"  location="${build.dir}/test-reports"/>

    <!--
    ===========
    Build setup
    ===========
    -->
    <target name="init">
        <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" />

        <ivy:report todir='${ivy.reports.dir}' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="runtime.path" conf="runtime"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>

        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.reports.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!--
    ===============
    Compile target
    ===============
    -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="true" debug="true" classpathref="runtime.path"/>
    </target>

    <!--
    =====================
    Build and run targets
    =====================
    -->
    <target name="run" depends="init-ivy">
        <java classname="org">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="runtime.path"/>
                <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <!--
    =============
    Clean targets
    =============
    -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: What exactly is your error? I noticed that your "run" target has a "depends" attribute that calls an ivy related target but does not compile your code. Is this the problem? Missing classes at runtime because the local source has not been compiled? Finally you stated it's not working from Eclipse. This is missleading as ivy is an ANT plugin. Have you tried running ANT from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/ivybeans/issues/detail?id=58) in ivy..and this happens due to that. Take a look at the bug and its resolution that people have given. It worked for me . The resolution is that you have to disable compile on save option for your project. Check if this helps.